# Mouse over event in Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

I am a beginner.Does anyone know how to create a mouse  cursor in and out event in Microsoft Expression Blend for Visual Studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

[This short video](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/234/Default.aspx) can help you to do a mouseover event using Expression Blend with vs2013.

Note: At 3:43 second you can see the mouseover event on behaviors tab.

Comment: What u have mentioned is a CSS but here i am doing a c# application in that case i don't find it very useful.. thanks for the effort anyway if possible please reconsider it using the C#